# android video transfer crash

Tags: video, nexus-one, file-transfer

I'm trying to transfer video files to my phone, [HTC Google Nexus One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_One) ([Android 2.3.6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Gingerbread_2.3.x)), but with this strange behaviour:

- After I copy file to the phone, when I'm opening it with computer it works ok.
- After turning off USB mass storage, I open the video file with my phone's video players and it's not opening.
- When I mount the phone to computer again and try to open it with the computer video players it again can't open.

**I suppose that:**

- The problem is not with video encoding, since it can be opened the first time, from the PC.
- It can be opened from the PC after I transfer it to the phone, so the problem is not with cable or transfer either.

The fact is, that after I unmount phone from my computer, the video crashes and can't be opened either by the phone or the PC!!!!

Can someone help me with this?

I will be very appreciated.

Comment: Video format might not be compatible with the phone's player.  But if the PC can't play it either, you may have a corruption due to an incomplete write.  Are you unmounting the phone from the host OS, then disabling mass storage on the phone itself, before pulling the cable?  After a reconnection, using a tool like diff to check the version on the phone against the source version on the PC would be a good test.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a corrupted file. You most probably pulled the cable before everything was written to disk. Compare original and copied file by calculating both md5sums and see if they match:

Open office' site has a comprehensive guide how to do that on Windows and Linux (same on MacOS). 
http://www.openoffice.org/dev_docs/using_md5sums.html

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by downloading [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) from the Play Store (it's free), then put the videos that won't copy in a ZIP file - which you copy to your Android device and extract them there.

I successfully played those videos using the VLC beta version.